# What is unclear about the TASS-Kremlin line question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

[Does TASS have a disclosed direct line with the Kremlin?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/71931/does-tass-have-a-disclosed-direct-line-with-the-kremlin)

was closed as unclear. I have no idea how to clarify it more than I have done so already.

Suggestions?

Comment: **VTR.** I have no suggestions, sorry. It is crystal clear to me what is being asked. I have no answer, but the Q is 100% answerable, provided enough knowledge. Also, closing a question with a canned **and** clearly incorrect message **and without any constructive comments** as to how best to reopen the question goes against the principles of this site as being mostly objective and friendly. But this is another issue altogether; this will get addressed in a separate Meta question of its own. :)

Comment: I don’t think it should be closed, and I see it’s been reopened, but the “unclear” might have been based on what you mean by hotline. You mention a physical hotline phone which seems kind of obsolete nowadays. Regular phones and email are plenty sufficient to coordinate propaganda  with the kremlin, so maybe a real answer should be broader? That’s at least what went though my head when I saw the question - I figured it could be helpful

Comment: @divibisan: yeah, I'm sure there can be a lot of informal ways, the way stuff sometimes happens in Washington; IIRC Trump used to [call](https://nymag.com/intelligencer/2018/05/sean-hannity-donald-trump-late-night-calls.html) some of his favorite anchors to offload or rant etc., but to have an official secure line with a press org is what's not so common, IMHO. I have to sign off soon, but I'll look at the Q again later so see if I can make that more clear.